# WMS layers don't draw in QGIS or ArcMap but do in OpenLayers

Tags: qgis, arcmap, wms, arccatalog, sql-server-spatial

WMS Map was published by myself in AutoDesk Infrastructure Map Server 2013. I can connect and load detials (properties / metadata) in QGIS Browser, ArcCatelog. I can load the wms into QGIS desktop and ArcGIS desktop but the layers do not draw (in the mapframe) in either program.  I can isolate and draw the layers in OpenLayers html file just fine. The only thing that concens me is a SQL Spatial layer in the Map created using ArcSquirrel.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with not displayed is the EPSG.

Have you verified your project fits the requested EPSG?

Comment: Thanks for Replying Chris,Yes, Iv'e supplied 2 EPSGs with the WMS and have tried to access it from both EPSGs.

Comment: And your Project fits one of both without need of "on-the-fly" conversion?

Comment: I believe so.  One of the origin files is a shapefile in UTM (EPSG:26917). When I published the WMS service from AIMS I asked for it to be published in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and UTM 26917. My getCapabilites shows both are available. I setup ArcMap, QGIS in either system and nothing draws. The TOC shows the Service, Group and Layers. In QGIS it states 0 of 0 bytes downloaded in bottom left hand corner of the screen.  In Openlayers i ask for it in EPSG:4326 and it displays in the browser no problem. Thanks again Chris.

Comment: The Layers are listed / EPSG reported independendly from the drawing at the canvas. So listing doesnt mean its displayable.

Could you please give be the URL of your WMS service?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post it as some data is sensitive. Do you have a way I can contact you? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In AIMS' Admin Site changed the Configure WMS from localhost:8008 to your IP or Domain Address. 8008 is the default and needs to be changed to support your webserver port.